# Кавычки в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query="select pass from userlist where name='{$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]}'";
```

для чего такая запись: name='{$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]}' ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки в PHP бывают двух видов: в одинарных кавычках и без. Одинарные кавычки просто содержат строки, а двойные кавычки предварительно парсятся.
Под парсингом подразумеваются две вещи: замена всяких управляющих конструкций (`\r\n` и подобное) и подстановка переменных. Здесь применяется именно подстановка переменных.

Синтаксис `{$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]}` означает, что подставляется значение массива `$_SERVER`, находящееся под ключом `PHP_AUTH_USER`. Фигурные скобки применяются для отделения переменной от весго остального, если не ошибаюсь, можно было бы обойтись и без них.

Таким образом в финале получится такая штука:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = 'vasya';
$query="select pass from userlist where name='{$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]}'";
// где-то в дебрях парсера
$query="select pass from userlist where name='vasya'";
```

Одинарные кавычки внутри строки нужны, потому что иначе SQL-сервер воспримет переданное не за строку,а за переменную (точно так же, как PHP полез бы искать константу).

А еще в PHP разрешены такие штуки:

```
$a = 12;
$b = 'a';
echo $$b; // 12

$x = new stdClass;
$b = 'COUNT(*)';
$x->$b = 12;
$c = '*)';
echo $x->{'COUNT('.$c}; //12
```